# how to find in xsd, whether the particular tag is available in xml or not?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-validation

My xml file is,

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <type xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                          
                    xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="datatype.xsd">

    <int>integer</int>
    <varchar>varcharacter</varchar>
    <double>doubles</double> 

  </type>
```

In this xml, I want to set `<float></float>` as mandatory. But i didn't use this tag. So how to validate the `<float>` is present or not in my xml file, using xsd with java.? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used to validate your XML against a schema:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("datatype.xsd"));

        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
        validator.validate(source);
    }

}
```

For a more detailed example see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html

Comment: @Doughan: I had this code, now I wants validate whether the particular tag is already available or not in the xml using XSD.

Comment: In your implementation of ErrorHandler you will be able to catch  SAXParseExceptions thrown by the validation.  From that you will be able to determine if any are related to a particular tag being absent.